# How to generate ten million test/sample records for SQL Server Address Table (AddressID, FirstLine, SecondLine, State, Country) quickly?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Database: SQL Server 2019

Table name:
Address

```
Columns: 
AddressID Varchar(20)
FirstLine Varchar(400)
SecondLine Varchar(400)
State      Varchar (100)
Country    Varchar (50)
```

Sample Data:

```
AddrID0001 | Some Random Street | Some Random Apt | NH | US 
AddrID0002 | ueiwoqtyr uiyweqry qow iuyuiwqye | ewquyrtweq Apt 4| CA | US 
AddrID0003 | rtyewqr yuwqtert  oiyqewiru  | ewquyrtweq utyewqr | NC| US 
etc.
```

If these random placeholders can be replaced by actual names, that will be great but not necessary.

Comment: Is "quickly" really the only goal? How often are you generating _10 million random rows_ that it matters whether it takes 4 seconds or 19 seconds or 28 seconds?

Comment: Cross join your single sample address to a [tally table](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/12/t-sql-queries/number-series-challenge) is one way. But I suspect that you might actually need randomized values that more accurately reflect your real situation - which is a far more complex issue.

Answer (score 1):

Create a table with a few records.For example, 10 records. Then fill the destination table with the following code and writing the desired number in front of the GO command

```
INSERT INTO Address
VALUES (
    (SELECT TOP 1 FirstLine FROM tbl ORDER BY NEWID()) ,
    (SELECT TOP 1 SecondLine FROM tbl ORDER BY NEWID()) ,
    (SELECT TOP 1 State FROM tbl ORDER BY NEWID()) ,
    (SELECT TOP 1 Country FROM tbl ORDER BY NEWID())
)
GO 10000000
```

With this `GO 10000000` command, `INSERT` queries will be executed 10000000 times

Comment: Thank you for your input Mostafa NZ. This solution works but take much longer time to create these records. I used this solution VS solution given below (using CTE Cross Joins). Given below solutions by "Luuk" is much faster. Also, it generates random values as expected in question.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH  cte as (
   select CAST(0 AS INT) as x
   union all
   select x+1 from cte where x<9)
INSERT INTO Address
SELECT
  CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT('AddrID0' , cte1.x),  cte2.x) , cte3.x) , cte4.x) , cte5.x) , cte6.x) , cte7.x) as AddressID,
  REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),'-',' '),'Q',' ') as FirstLine,
  REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),'-',' '),'Q',' ') as SecondLine,
  'NH',
  'US'
FROM cte as cte1
CROSS JOIN cte as cte2
CROSS JOIN cte as cte3
CROSS JOIN cte as cte4
CROSS JOIN cte as cte5
CROSS JOIN cte as cte6
CROSS JOIN cte as cte7
-- ORDER BY 1
;
```

output of this query:

```
select * from (
(select * from (select top(3) * from Address  ORDER by AddressID asc) x1 )
union all 
(select * from (select top(3) * from Address order by AddressID desc)  x2)
) y;
```

will be something (because of the random output of `NEWID()`) like:

| AddressID | FirstLine | SecondLine | State | Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AddrID00000000 | 21348E1C D239 4DC5 AA28 3D609919C9C4 | AD9C16F1 9B9D 49F9 A249 7893C7EBEDBC | NH | US |
| AddrID00000001 | D9BDAF89 9147 4F8E BBCB 0345411B7DD8 | 79C50237 2181 45A2 8551 2A574DD71145 | NH | US |
| AddrID00000002 | 83818A03 A341 4ED7 AEB8 001CC4162276 | 9301BDF4 F456 484F BE8C DCDD7EB44060 | NH | US |
| AddrID09999999 | D22C6EBB DC33 4572 96F4 8C24C350BEB0 | 21C946B6 0ECB 46A7 99A0 569B43C3275C | NH | US |
| AddrID09999998 | A52E42DD 7BBA 4440 89D3 825176ED0159 | CCBD542F 28E9 449D 8A4C 9AA5ED4E9923 | NH | US |
| AddrID09999997 | 02F640F6 786E 43D4 95F6 F80A4AA10CA3 | 88AB6376 65F7 4B5B 9C9C 78D67822B1CD | NH | US |

- It's up to you to fill `State` with something random.
- "quickly" is a relative word, on my system it took about 2 minutes.
- The REPLCE in First- and SecondLine is just a simple attempt to create random length words, and is open for improvement when you have more imagination than I have currently...

Answer (score 0):

you can check this. This script will create a sample "Sales" table with millions of unique records.

You can change the Table name as well as the fields depends on what you want.

```
    --      Declare Variables

    DECLARE     @Counter INT
    DECLARE     @FromDate DATETIME2(0)
    DECLARE     @ToDate   DATETIME2(0)
    DECLARE     @TotalNumOfRows Int

    SET     @Counter=1
    SET     @TotalNumOfRows=4000000 --You can change this number depends on how many records you want to create. On this example the total rows will be created is 4 million.

    --      Create Temporary Table

    Create Table #Temptb 
    (
        Customer_No Nvarchar(50),
        Receipt_No Nvarchar(10),
        Receipt_date DateTime,
        Item_No INT,
        Qty INT,
        Price Decimal(18, 2)
    )

    WHILE       ( @Counter <= @TotalNumOfRows) 
    BEGIN
            SET @FromDate = '2001-01-01 00:00:00' --This is for Receipt date, this will be for the beginning receipt date.
            SET @ToDate = '2023-07-27 23:59:59' --This is for Receipt date, this will be for the ending receipt date.

            DECLARE @Seconds INT = DATEDIFF(SECOND, @FromDate, @ToDate)
            DECLARE @Random INT = ROUND(((@Seconds-1) * RAND()), 0)

            Insert Into #Temptb
            SELECT  Customer_No     =   CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),
                    Receipt_No      =   'R' + RIGHT('0000000' + CAST(@Counter AS VARCHAR(7)),7),
                    Receipt_date    =   DATEADD(SECOND, @Random, @FromDate),
                    Item_No         =   FLOOR(RAND()*(5000-1000)+1000), -- SELECT RAND()*(b-a)+a; Where a is the smallest number and b is the largest number that you want to generate a random number for.
                    Qty             =   FLOOR(RAND()*(100-1)+1),
                    Price           =   RAND()*(50-1)+1

            SET @Counter = @Counter  + 1
    END


    --      Create Table Sales

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sales](
        [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [Customer_No] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
        [Receipt_No] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
        [Receipt_date] [date] NOT NULL,
        [Item_No] [int] NOT NULL,
        [Qty] [int] NOT NULL,
        [Price] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
        [Amount] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
        [Date_Created] [date] NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [ID] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    --      Insert Data to Sales Table

    INSERT INTO Sales
    SELECT  Customer_No,
            Receipt_No,
            Receipt_date,
            Item_No,
            Qty,
            Price,
            Qty * Price,
            Receipt_date as Date_Created
    FROM    #Temptb

    Drop Table #Temptb
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**